# Blender does not render a scene that was previously rendered successfully

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Blender no longer wants to render a scene that I have previously rendered successfully. Suddenly, when I start the render, the whole PC freezes and I can only restart it with hard reset. I assume it has something to do with the texture size, because when I lowered the texture limit from 8192 to 128, the scene rendered fine. But as I said, I rendered the scene a few times at 8192 and it worked fine. I tried cleaning up the project (didn't help). The only changes I made were adding more cameras.

Comment: maybe it has to do with the dimension, is it set to 100%?